# Avoid chrome remote Desktop notification

Tags: windows-8, chrome-remote-desktop

How i can remove that notification that appear in the bottom of desktop when we access other computer that says (Your desktop is currently shared with email ) by using chrome remote desktop? I am using window 8. if somebody know please help me.